# Lost Security claims identity in different controller

Tags: c#, authentication, claims-based-identity

I'm working on WebAPI 2 project. I'm using Security claims identity for Authentication. When I'm accessing HomeController HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is present. But when I redirect to another Controller HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is null.

```
Controller code - 
 [RequirePermenantEmployee]
    public class EstimationController : BaseApiController
    {
}    

Autherization code -
public class RequirePermenantEmployee : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
if (HttpContext.Current.User == null || HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null ||
                HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            {}
}
```

Above is the sample Code for Authorization. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is available in HomeController only. Its not available for other controllers. Can you please let me know the how to fix this?

Comment: Which authentication are you using? Also what is the authentication mode set in web.config? Are you using async call in somewhere?

Comment: do you use an authorization attribute ?

Comment: Authentication mode is None in web.config. And i using this as authorization attribute on controller level. 
I am just trying to post file using Ajax post on another controller, but claims are not accessible

Comment: For what do you want to use the claims ? Only for checking if the user is authenticated to request the controller ?

Comment: Claims we are using authentication as well as authorization purpose.

Comment: Did you import the HttpContext in the other Controller ? Can you provide some more code ?

Comment: Do you redirect from the `HomeController` to `DemoController` or is the `DemoController` requested by an user ?

Comment: I redirect from HomeController to EstimationController in my case using ajax post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176304/discussion-between-vikas-pawar-and-dometune).

Answer (score 0):

finally, i figured out the root cause for this. I just commented following code in WebAPIconfig file and it started working

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```